# Jquery ToggleClass not toggling between two classes

Tags: jquery

I have these two elements:

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

I also have a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
```

What I am trying to do toggle between the two classes using jquery toggleClass like so:

```
$('#checkbox').click(function () {
        $(".urlWrapper .fileWrapper").toggleClass("urlWrapper fileWrapper");
    });
```

But its not toggling between the two....what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to select an element with both classes or two separated elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve, it appears that you have two div's with different class names than you are trying to effect. Is the below what you are looking for?

```js
$('#checkbox').on("click",function () {
        $(".a").toggleClass("urlWrapper fileWrapper");
        $(".b").toggleClass("urlWrapper fileWrapper");  
    });
```

```css
.urlWrapper {
  color : red;
 }

.fileWrapper {
  font-weight:bold;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="a urlWrapper">
      content 1
    </div>
    <div class="b fileWrapper">
      content 2
</div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more what you are looking for. The classes were `.a` and .b`instead of`.urlWrapper`and`.fileWrapper`. Also, you you need to have a comma to select multiple classes.

```js
$('#checkbox').click(function () {
  $(".urlWrapper, .fileWrapper").toggleClass("urlWrapper fileWrapper");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="urlWrapper">A</div>
<div class="fileWrapper">B</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
```